# Global variable in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i wrote an function to login user by rest api in flutter. I want to use response from post but i don't know how to export my variable into another file.

I want use `userID`, but i dont know how, 
can somebody help me?

```
class LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen>{

  makeLoginRequest(String email, password) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Map data = {
      'email':email,
      'password':password
    };
    var jsonResponse;
    var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:80/user/login';
    var response = await http.post(url, body:data);
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);

      int userID = jsonResponse['id'];//HERE

if(jsonResponse != null){
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonResponse['token']);
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => UserPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your UserPage use a variable to get the ID.

**Example:**

```
class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int userId;

  UserPage({@required this.userId});

  @override
  _UserPageState createState() => _UserPageState();
}

class _UserPageState extends State<UserPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

**While navigating to UserPage after login pass the userID:**

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => UserPage(userId: userID)), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

**When you want to get the value of userId in UserPage, you can use it in following way:** `widget.userId`

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are a god :D, but one question, ```widget.userId``` , how is the widget here? could you give some example of use in your post above?

Comment: "widget" here if a reference to the parent widget UserPage with we are using inside the state widget UserPageState.